# Flipping horizontal asterisk histogram to a vertical one in java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a vertical histogram from a horizontal histogram. I have tried with a similar nested loop setup but I can't seem to do it without breaking the code. I'm slowly learning from a textbook so I've only had experience with a limited number of functions.

The scaling with spaces in a vertical graph is a lot more difficult than I could manage unfortunately.

```
public static void main(String atgs[]) {
    int[] distribution = {0,1,8,59,215,703,1848,3975,8077,13937,22195,31628,
                        41711,51099,57142,59959,59670,55756,48850,40931,32583,
                        24995,18217,12794,8623,5577,3601,2272,1259,764,464,246,
                        153,80,39,22,12,6,3,0};

    final int MAX_COUNTS = distribution.length;

    System.out.println(String.format("%3s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s", " ", "0", "10000", "20000", "30000", "40000", "50000", "60000"));
    System.out.println("    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(String.format("%3s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s", " ", "|", "|", "|", "|", "|", "|", "|"));

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COUNTS; i++) {
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%3s %-1s", String.valueOf(i), "|"));

            int n = distribution[i] / 1000 + 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%1s", "*"));
            }
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.print(String.format("%-3s %-1s", " ", "|"));
            int n = distribution[i] / 1000 + 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%1s", "*"));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a vertical histogram is more complicated than a horizontal histogram.

Here are the results of your distribution array.

```
  60,000- |                                                                                 
          |                               * *                                               
          |                             * * *                                               
          |                             * * * *                                             
          |                             * * * *                                             
  50,000- |                           * * * * *                                             
          |                           * * * * * *                                           
          |                           * * * * * *                                           
          |                           * * * * * *                                           
          |                           * * * * * *                                           
  40,000- |                         * * * * * * * *                                         
          |                         * * * * * * * *                                         
          |                         * * * * * * * *                                         
          |                         * * * * * * * *                                         
          |                         * * * * * * * * *                                       
  30,000- |                       * * * * * * * * * *                                       
          |                       * * * * * * * * * *                                       
          |                       * * * * * * * * * *                                       
          |                       * * * * * * * * * * *                                     
          |                     * * * * * * * * * * * *                                     
  20,000- |                     * * * * * * * * * * * *                                     
          |                     * * * * * * * * * * * * *                                   
          |                     * * * * * * * * * * * * *                                   
          |                     * * * * * * * * * * * * *                                   
          |                   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *                                 
  10,000- |                   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *                                 
          |                 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *                               
          |                 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *                               
          |                 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *                             
          |               * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *                         
       0- | - - - - | - - - - | - - - - | - - - - | - - - - | - - - - | - - - - | - - - - 
          0                  10                  20                  30
```

The biggest "trick" I did was to create the vertical histogram upside down.  In other words, I created the X-axis label line first, then the dashed line, then the histogram lines from the bottom up.  I saved all the lines in a `java.util.List`, then printed the output lines in reverse order.

I broke the code up into seven methods, not including the `main` method.  I did this so I could focus on one part of the vertical histogram at a time.

I did not write all this code in one shot.  I built one vertical histogram line at a time.  I built the vertical histogram first, then added the Y-Axis labels.  I tested.  I probably ran 50 - 70 tests before I completed the code.

I used a `StringBuilder` to construct each line.  You could concatenate `String` segments together, but a `StringBuilder` is more efficient.

Here's the complete, runnable code.  I hope you review the code and try to understand what I did.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VerticalHistogram {
    
    public static void main(String atgs[]) {
        VerticalHistogram vh = new VerticalHistogram();
        
        int[] distribution = { 0, 1, 8, 59, 215, 703, 1848, 3975, 8077, 
                13937, 22195, 31628, 41711, 51099, 57142, 59959,
                59670, 55756, 48850, 40931, 32583, 24995, 18217, 
                12794, 8623, 5577, 3601, 2272, 1259, 764, 464, 246,
                153, 80, 39, 22, 12, 6, 3, 0 };
            vh.createVerticalHistogram(distribution);
    }
    
    private NumberFormat numberFormat;
    
    public VerticalHistogram() {
        this.numberFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
    }
    
    public void createVerticalHistogram(int[] distribution) {
        int maximum = calculateMaximum(distribution);
        maximum = roundUp(maximum, 1000);
        
        // 30 is maximum height of histogram
        int interval = maximum / 30; 
        int labelInterval = interval * 5;
//      System.out.println(maximum + " " + interval);
        
        List<String> output = generateVerticalHistogram(distribution, 
                interval, labelInterval, maximum);
        for(int i = output.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(output.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    private int calculateMaximum(int[] distribution) {
        int max = distribution[0];
        
        for (int i = 1; i < distribution.length; i++) {
            max = Math.max(max, distribution[i]);
        }
        
        return max;
    }
    
    private List<String> generateVerticalHistogram(int[] distribution, 
            int interval, int labelInterval, int max) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        output.add(generateXLabels(distribution));
        output.add(generateXAxis(distribution));
        
        for (int value = interval; value <= max; value += interval) {
            output.add(generateYValue(distribution, value, labelInterval));
        }
        
        return output;
    }
    
    private String generateXLabels(int[] distribution) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("          ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++) {
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                builder.append(i);
            } else {
                builder.append("  ");
            }
        }
        
        return builder.toString();
    }
    
    private String generateXAxis(int[] distribution) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("       ");
        builder.append(numberFormat.format(0));
        builder.append("- ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++) {
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                builder.append("| ");
            } else {
                builder.append("- ");
            }
        }
        
        return builder.toString();
    }
    
    private String generateYValue(int[] distribution, int value, 
            int labelInterval) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (value % labelInterval == 0) {
            String label = numberFormat.format(value);
            int margin = 8 - label.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < margin; i++) {
                builder.append(" ");
            }
            builder.append(label).append("- | ");
        } else {
            builder.append("          | ");
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++) {
            if (distribution[i] >= value) {
                builder.append("* ");
            } else {
                builder.append("  ");
            }
        }
        
        return builder.toString();
    }
    
    private int roundUp(int max, int factor) {
        return (max + factor - 1) / factor * factor;
    }

}
```